# Unable to figure out jQuery deferred done

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am new to **jquery** deferred and I spent a while looking at similar questions on here but to no avail. I could use some help

I have a function that **grabs the form input values** and a f**unction that saves those values**. The form inputs values are not being grabbed fast enough before the save items function executes. I am trying to solve this by using jquery deferred but cannot get it to work. I also tried to use .when and .done.
When I hard coded the parameters in my js file, Attempt 2 worked but not when I passed parameters on an onclick or in my console.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Attempt 1:**

```
function deferredTest1(w,x,y,z) {

    var d1 = $.Deferred();
    d1.done(function() {

    SaveNewItem(x,y,z);

});

function getFormValues(w) {
     $(w).each(function(i,obj) {
     var input = $(this).val();
     var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
     str = str.concat(",'"+inputID+"':'"+input+"'");  
     });

 }

 d1.resolve();

}
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
function deferredTest2(w,x,y,z) {

    var formvalues = getFormValues(w);
    $.when(formvalues).done(SaveNewItem(x,y,z));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, they're "not being grabbed fast enough"? Grab them, then save.

Comment: Very helpful comment, sir, thank you so much! Well they are being stored in the variable str, you see. The issue is that getFormValues function isn't executing before the SaveNewItem function. So empty values are being saved...

Comment: *Why* isn't it executing before saving a new item? When you click/submit/whatever call it *there*. Why are you storing them in a global variable?

Comment: Why isn't it is why I posted the question. I'm storing them in a global variable because i need to be able to pass that variable in my SaveNewItem function.

Comment: ... This sounds like an XY problem. The *problem* is that you're storing them in a global variable instead of doing it at the point *you're actually saving them*. You're missing my point: why are you trying to save them somewhere other than when you're actually *using* them? There *may* be an actual technical/business reason, but until you articulate what it is, this seems like a very convoluted way to do something that's trivial.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding why there's anything complicated here. You must have a click/etc handler that does the save. You're already using jQuery, and I'm assuming something happens in `SaveNewItem` (unconventionally named, btw) that makes a request to something. Serialize the values there.

Comment: So, here is the thing, I'm a beginner so I'm having a hard time understanding in general. There is very much a purpose for having the global variable. I am at a loss for how to articulate it. Hopefully when I come back to this questions months down the line I will laugh at how easy the solution was. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is only very rarely a need for a global variable, and they're dangerous in JavaScript. Good luck!

Comment: There's also hardly ever a reason to use a deferred/promise when you only have synchronous operations such as your `.each()` loop.  You can just program synchronous operations with sequential lines of code and don't need promises or deferreds to manage them as they only complicate synchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your second try was closest. The `$.when` call takes a deferred, so we create one first, then use that in the `$.when` call. It is resolved in the `getFormValues` method after the loop is completed. At this time the `then` callback is executed.

```
var deferred = $.Deferred();
function deferredTest3(w,x,y,z) {
    $.when(deferred).then(function () {
        SaveNewItem(x,y,z);
    });
}
function getFormValues(w) {
    $(w).each(function(i,obj) {
        var input = $(this).val();
        var inputID = $(this).attr('id');
        str = str.concat(",'"+inputID+"':'"+input+"'");  
    });
    deferred.resolve();
}
```

There is no asynchronous action here though, so a deferred is not necessary. A deferred is used to manage various asynchronous requests and their callbacks if they depend on one another.